# Code obfuscation using certificate in c#

Tags: c#, dll, obfuscation

I have c# dll that runs on client machine at remote location. I want to obfuscate my code before giving it to client.
The aim is to stop the dll from disassembling or breaking my code or my code being visible to untrusted user. I want to do that using a certificate.
I am using c# for programming.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: How will buying .Net reactor help me?

Comment: Is it not possible to stop disassembling by using a certificate?

Comment: (What's a "certificate" in this context?)  Why would a certificate stop anybody from looking at the bytes of the DLL?  If they can do that, they can start to disassemble it.

Comment: Hi Ira,
Thanks for the response.
The certificate can be any password protected .pfx file. I may be wrong.
So is there any way with which i can stop my code from getting disassembled?
Can i use Visual Studio...may be if i can write some lines of code which will stop the untrusted user from disassembling it?
Using a third party tool is my last option.

Comment: @Ravi, a certificate just signs the code so that the code is identified as coming from your company, I don't believe it does any obfuscation or encryption

Comment: .NET Reactor will help you obfuscate your C# code